# GitHub Desktop doesnt pick and push the entire repository

Tags: github

I am using GitHub desktop application on my local machine and when I create and complete my repository(web directory)on my local machine, then I push it GitHub online through desktop application. But here is my problem:

Sometimes it doesn't pick and push all of the files/folders from my local repository, it only pick 3 files, while my repository has 5 folders and one inex.html file. 
And sometimes it works perfectly fine. I never understand where is my problem. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: A git push doesn't consist of files, but of commits. If files are missing, then it is because they were not committed in the first place. (Another possibility would be that you're pushing wrong commits, which could happen if you're doing more complex things like branches or specific parameters to push, but I doubt that's what you're experiencing).

Comment: I understand your point, but I guess its the application problem or maybe I am not using the application properly.

Comment: @John, it's more likely that you're not using it properly. But you haven't really told us what you're doing so we can't help fix your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `git status` before your push, as well as a `git show HEAD` to check the content of your last commit.

That way, you will see if there remain some files not added to the index or not committed.
And you will see if every files you wanted is in a commit.

If one file is consistently ignored, see if it is actually ignored by Git with:

```
git check-ignored -v -- a/file
```